# How to make a random matrix without numpy

Tags: python, matrix, random

I came across this problem: create a random matrix without numpy.

I searched a bit for the term, but I didn't get it. Do u have to re-seed everytime I'm searching for a random number? My solution to this was:

```
import random

def matrix_random_number(n_filas, n_columnas, num_decimals=2):
    blank = [0]
    row = blank*n_filas
    array = [row]*n_columnas
    
    for j in range(n_columnas):
        for i in range(n_filas):
            array[j][i] = random.randint(0,100*10**num_decimals)/10**num_decimals
    return array
```

But my output was:

```
[[80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97],
 [80.91, 47.46, 15.86, 77.16, 92.47, 54.92, 2.76, 97.42, 14.99, 15.97]]
```

So that this is clearly not random. How to improve? Why is this bad code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your problem is making `n` copies of the same row object.  I'd recommend fixing this with a nested list comprehension.  That way there's no need for temporary variables, multiple passes on the matrix being generated, or appends.  This could be a 1-liner, but it would be an extremely long line so I've created a lambda for the random number generation and split it into two lines:

```python
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint

def matrix_random_number(n_filas, n_columnas, num_decimals=2):
    gen_value = lambda decimals: randint(0,100*10**decimals)/10**decimals
    return [[gen_value(num_decimals) for _ in range(n_filas)] for _ in range(n_columnas)]

pprint(matrix_random_number(7, 10, 3))
```

Sample output:

```
[[59.742, 5.339, 91.339, 20.221, 81.702, 45.815, 23.141],
 [32.716, 29.27, 89.193, 4.021, 79.846, 93.345, 61.367],
 [47.356, 33.87, 40.541, 68.483, 45.646, 64.898, 89.818],
 [84.371, 12.451, 76.413, 23.809, 0.591, 77.24, 12.813],
 [9.277, 31.923, 2.892, 68.653, 14.253, 14.225, 70.227],
 [91.887, 79.071, 13.206, 45.259, 73.019, 24.426, 82.332],
 [96.539, 6.743, 38.21, 55.292, 11.639, 56.902, 46.614],
 [36.961, 58.359, 79.174, 1.52, 38.937, 93.708, 25.964],
 [47.933, 62.434, 80.944, 54.694, 31.286, 84.219, 7.059],
 [82.522, 3.77, 85.51, 11.485, 83.059, 89.95, 38.618]]
```

There is no need to re-seed, and in fact doing so would be counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was searching for. Using comprehension overpowered in Python and just simple and clean.

Answer (score 1):

You used `array = [row]*n_columnas`. This makes every term in this `array` *the same* object, `row`. Thus all items in the rows are the same. You could create an empty `array` and add a `list` object every time. For example:

```
import random

def matrix_random_number(n_filas, n_columnas, num_decimals=2):
    array = []
    
    for j in range(n_columnas):
        array.append([])  # Add a list to the array
        for i in range(n_filas):
            array[j].append(random.randint(0,100*10**num_decimals)/10**num_decimals)  # Add number to row
    return array
```

will give the answer you want.

Comment: Yes, this is maybe more straightforward, but it doesn't make clear maybe what I'm filling out. Good job explaining the problem though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with seeding the random number generator, it because you're creating a matrix that references the same row list `n_columnas` times.
This can be easily fixed by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to initially create the empty matrix:

```
from pprint import pprint
import random


def matrix_random_number(n_filas, n_columnas, num_decimals=2):
    array = [[0 for _ in range(n_filas)] for _ in range(n_columnas)]

    for j in range(n_columnas):
        for i in range(n_filas):
            array[j][i] = random.randint(0,100*10**num_decimals)/10**num_decimals
    return array

array = matrix_random_number(7, 10)
pprint(array)
```

Sample output:

```
[[12.88, 47.27, 95.93, 60.3, 1.49, 6.75, 90.73],
 [6.87, 53.84, 78.22, 69.36, 62.34, 5.5, 66.63],
 [10.29, 42.7, 55.67, 25.68, 39.48, 91.17, 3.96],
 [59.77, 88.4, 52.77, 84.35, 21.0, 69.19, 35.0],
 [85.63, 10.75, 29.8, 67.25, 0.12, 58.79, 42.46],
 [34.87, 45.07, 25.64, 4.74, 71.25, 31.57, 83.94],
 [32.61, 41.17, 98.27, 88.85, 30.23, 62.89, 84.26],
 [82.04, 17.88, 75.25, 56.83, 51.69, 91.16, 32.7],
 [66.66, 56.21, 39.0, 6.27, 87.61, 70.42, 56.06],
 [49.68, 22.95, 78.53, 98.12, 74.47, 18.45, 94.32]]
```

Comment: I personally don't like that much assigning values to the matrix, instead, filling them directly, but thanks for your support it really fixes the problem.

Comment: Only did it this way to show you a proper way to pre-allocate the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit and it works now, a pretty simple solution in my opinion which doesn't change your code that much

```
import random

def matrix_random_number(n_filas, n_columnas, num_decimals=2):
    array = []

    for j in range(n_columnas):
        array.append([])
        for _ in range(n_filas):
            array[j].append(random.randint(0,100*10**num_decimals)/10**num_decimals)
    return array

print(matrix_random_number(7,10))
```

Output:

```
[[59.68, 73.58, 36.42, 67.03, 44.81, 44.43, 80.57], 
[26.0, 29.65, 23.18, 30.5, 9.19,35.47, 74.88],
[96.48, 29.79, 83.88, 2.54, 61.0, 6.93, 4.02],
[16.81, 88.3, 90.25, 93.95, 86.14, 55.68, 77.68],
[34.88, 87.94, 88.0, 15.74, 31.41, 68.25, 81.91],
[91.7, 2.09, 35.24, 71.55, 67.84, 65.35, 98.99],
[85.21, 65.26, 17.36, 44.8, 57.91, 67.54, 35.84],
[34.71, 19.63, 19.0, 57.81, 51.68, 98.75, 28.89],
[5.72, 42.76, 10.39, 18.22, 78.95, 73.45, 43.45],
[50.77, 15.71, 81.22, 64.02, 24.93, 71.04, 48.53]]
```

Comment: You should explain what the original problem was and how your solution fixes it.